# JDBC create Data Source requires restart - Websphere 9.0

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, websphere-9

I am creating a JDBC data source in websphere. Everything works fine for the creation part. So when I test connection from websphere Data Sources the connection is successful. But if I try to access it through the browser like going to

http://10.10.10.23:9090/TestJdbCResourceName/ I get a Sql Exception.

And I would expect to get `Connection: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@f9cf6468`

But all I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1705)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:613)
    at com.test.testHello.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4115)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1028)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2523)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1840)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3840)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3116)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:646)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:68)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1365)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2154)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1787)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1113)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2162)
    ... 31 more
```

When I restart Websphere and try the exact the same thing it works.

But restart is not an option as other applications are running on websphere.

Not sure why this is requiring a restart and not working straight after creation. (As it works from Data Sources test connection)

What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server traditional, which you are using, does not support updates to data sources without a server restart, which is why you see errors when you attempt it.  For the sake of others who might read this answer in the future, it should be clarified that WebSphere Application Server Liberty does support configuration updates to data sources without server restart, but that will not help in your case because you are using the traditional WebSphere Application Server edition.

The reason that you can see it succeed via the test connection operation is that the test connection operation does not exercise normal product codepath through the connection manager and simply forms a connection directly via the JDBC driver.  Given that all of your configuration is correct, this succeeds, whereas accessing the data source through JNDI (production codepath) fails.